# encrypter encripts same id's to different outputs

Tags: r

I am trying to encrypt a database that has several rows for the same ID.
Using "encryptr" package I get different results for the same ID.
How can I change this?

Sample code:

```
ID <- c('1','1','1')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
data <- data.frame(ID, salary)

data = 
  data %>%
  encryptr::encrypt(ID)

data
```

How can I force it to encode the same ID into the same encoded string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  From their web page https://encrypt-r.org:

> Not a hash
>
> The ciphertext produced for a given input will change with each
> encryption. This is a feature of the RSA algorithm. Ciphertexts should
> not therefore be attempted to be matched between datasets encrypted
> using the same public key. This is a conscious decision given the
> risks associated with sharing the necessary details (a salt).

Edited to add:

If you actually do want a hash, the `digest` package can calculate several.  It's designed to hash a whole vector at a time, but you can make it work on each element using `Vectorize`, e.g.

```
library(digest)
vdigest <- Vectorize(digest)
data <-
  data %>% mutate(hash = vdigest(ID)) %>% encryptr::encrypt(ID)
```

It's not easy to invert vdigest, so you probably want both the hash and the encrypted ID.

And do be aware that the `encryptr` authors knew what they were doing:  including the hash makes the encryption much less secure.